# How to estimate the occurrence time of an event for scheduling purposes precisely?

Tags: statistics

I working on a system in which a number of requests arrive in random time. Consider the following timeline:

[image]

In the above example, we have a certain number of components: `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. They send their requests to our system at random time. We can record the time that a request arrives in nanoseconds (I guess I can assume that my `T` variable is continues).

The event that I am interested in is seeing all the requests from all the components in whatever order. In the above example, these orders are as follows:

```
DBAC
ADCB
BACD
DACB
```

A component cannot send another request, until an already sent request gets satisfied. Each request may be dependent on some other requests. So, a request get satisfied either as soon as it arrives, or later on.

At timeouts, we satisfy all received requests up to that time. These timeouts are now fixed, and I am looking for a way to dynamically estimate and adjust the next timeout in such a way that all the requests have been received before the timeout, so I can schedule them correctly. Also the timeout should be bounded by a lower bound and a higher bound.

I have heard of a technique in the name of Survival or Reliability Analysis. How could I make use of this in context of my application? What should I measure? When should I measure?

Is there any other technique that can help me?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "in such a way that all the requests have been received before the timeout". You want a timeout as soon as you have an open request from each component? (but then you can just wait for that to happen, as long as that's within your bounds..)   
To clarify, can you say – in the example – at what point your ideal timeouts would be?

Comment: Also, apparently requests also get satisfied *between* timeouts, as indicated by the two successive B above. The first shouldn't trigger a timeout, even if A,C,D are already present, but the second should? Or what's the determining factor?

Comment: These request are coming at random times and random order. I want a timeout between different ordering.